# Как реализовать перебор?

Tags: python

Python 2.7.6, ОС Windows Запускаю в Notpade++

Для получения значения из тега использую данную конструкцию

```
from xml.dom.minidom import * 

xml = parse(path To file)
xml = xml.getElementsByTagName(‘Р1’)

Р = xml[0].firstChild.data

print P
```

но она возвращает только одно и тоже значение тега P Пример:1 связано это с xml[0] если в квадратных скобках поставить xml[1] то приходит значение тега во втором блоке. Теги не помечаются Р1 или Р2 различаются только содержанием.

```
<S>
     <P1>1</P1>
     <P2>2</P2>
</S>

     <S>
          <P1>3</P1>
          <P2>4</P2>
    </S>
```

Мне нужно что бы при повторном запуске скрипта она возвращала значение следующего тега P Пример: 2 
Содержание тегов P помещается в 2 разные переменные которые потом сравниваются в условии в зависимости равны они или нет выполняется остальная программа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы добиться того, что вы хотите, необходимо где-то хранить текущее состояние.
Это должно быть персистентное хранилище(*файл, база данных, но не переменная в этом же скрипте*), потому что оно должно переживать смерть скрипта.

Навскидку у меня 2 варианта:

- Удаляйте(или помечайте) обработанные элементы в исходном файле
- Храните где-нибудь(в соседнем файле, например) индекс последнего обработанного элемента

---

В случае, если раздельные запуски не нужны, просто предварительно соберите нужные данные в отдельный список

```
# Для примера парсим не файл, а строку
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

html = '''
<section>
  <S><P>1</P></S>    
  <S><P>2</P></S>
</section>
'''
xml = parseString(html)

list = [el.firstChild.data for el in xml.getElementsByTagName('P')]

print(list) # ['1', '2']
```

И потом просто работайте с элементами списка: `list[0]==list[1]`

---

Для свежей редакции xml сбор данных будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
p_list = [
    [
        S.getElementsByTagName('P1')[0].firstChild.data,
        S.getElementsByTagName('P2')[0].firstChild.data
    ] for S in xml.getElementsByTagName('S')
]

print(p_list) # [['1', '2'], ['3', '4']]
```

Comment: Не много XML в своём вопросе поправил. Вы предлагаете в строке html = ''' прописать все нужные строки документа ?

Comment: Не предлагаю, вы парсите файл, я строку. Это вызывает трудности?

Comment: Это задание вызывает у меня трудности в начале всё легко казалось теперь до массивов докатился.

Comment: Чем список значений хуже кучи переменных?

Comment: Не совсем дружу со списками, массивами с переменными проще и понятней. И задачи соответственно стараюсь так решать.

Comment: Лучше подружитесь)

Answer (score 3):

Не понял, чем вам не подходит цикл

```
for tag in xml.getElementsByTagName('p'):
    print tag.firstChild.data
```

Comment: Всё же мне нужно без цикла и без данного xml[0]  элемента нажимаю на запуск выдаёт данные нажимаю ещё раз выдаёт данные следующего таково же тега и.т.д Так как потом мне нужно сравнивать переменные, а у меня в них список получаться.

Comment: Дополните пожалуйста ответ если знаете.

Comment: Исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он конкретно описывал суть проблемы, и добавьте в него [mcve].

Comment: Дополнил код постарался конкретизировать вопрос.

Comment: Всё равно ничего не понятно. Что значит "при следующем использовании"? При повторном запуске скрипта? Что значит "нажимаю на запуск"? Где нажимаете? В IDE?

Comment: И непонятно, какие переменные вам надо сравнивать "потом". И что мешает обойти список и сравнить его элементы.

Comment: При повторном запуске скрипта... Он вопрос дополнил.

Comment: При повторном запуске скрипта? Всё верно. Где нажимаете? В Notepad++ Содержание тегов P помещается в 2 разные которые потом сравниваются в условии в зависимости равны они или нет выполняется остальная программа.

Comment: "что мешает обойти список и сравнить его элементы". Вот этого не понимаю я поэтому и пытаюсь решить задачу на мой взгляд понятным мне методом. Если вы объясните как правильно то только буду рад этому.

Comment: * примечание переменные

Comment: Переменных с первого запуска уже не существует. Как вы собираетесь их сравнивать? Или это внешняя программа сравнивает выводы разных запусков?

Comment: Да всё верно как, правильно тогда сделать получить данные из блока S /S тега Р1 и Р2 добавить их в переменную перейти к другому блоку S /S получить из него данные тега Р1 иР2 добавить их в переменную. Сравнить эти переменные и так далее пока документ не кончиться ?

Comment: Извиняюсь не верно прописал XML